# Avoid Building Multiple Solutions Present Under Single Git Repo in Teamcity

Tags: git, github, teamcity

Following is our git repo structure

```
GitRepo
  |
  |-Provisioning
  |        |-Provisioning.sln
  |
  |-Source
  |     |-Deployment.sln
```

We have created two separate Teamcity projects for Provisioning and Deployment.

1. Teamcity.Application.Provisioning (Pointing to Provisioning.sln)
2. Teamcity.Application.Deployment (Pointing to Deployment.sln)

In both the teamcity projects we have given the same Git Repo URL in 'Fetch URL' setting while configuring VCS Root. Now, when we perform CheckIn in 'Source' folder Builds of both the teamcity projects are getting triggered as Git Repo URL is same.

Our expectation is if we perform CheckIn in 'Source' folder only build of Teamcity.Application.Deployment should be trigger.

Is there any way control this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this using VCS checkout rules:

Inside your Build: `Provisionning` set the checkout rule like this:

```
+:Provisioning => Provisioning
```

And inside your `Deployment` build, you can set the checkout rule like this:

```
+:Source => Source
```

If you need, you can remap your checkout Folder to match your expectations.

In my case, when I need to do this, I prefere to use some variables to define the checkout Path and modify it a single point:

VCS checkout rule : `+:%SrcFolder% => %SrcFolder%`
BuildStep: `msbuild %srcFolder%/MyApp.sln`
So I can share the build configuration to multiple projects using templates.

Comment: This is perfect solution. You save our life :) Thanks @Didier

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the 'trigger' part of your build settings, you could specify the relative path to watch (syntax could be done by include or exclude patterns)

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-TriggeringaBuildonBranchMerge